# Sql request for some reason duplicates all content

Tags: sql, session, joomla

I wrote sql request to retrieve joomla articles along with authors:

```
static function getLists(&$params)
    {
        $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
        $lists  = null;
        $query = "SELECT cc.title AS category, a.id, a.title, a.created as created, av.add_image as imgthrumb, ua.avatar as avatar, ar.intotext as introtext, ss.userid as onlineid,
        u.id AS userlink, u.username as username, u.lastvisitDate as lastvisit, a.hits, cc.id as catid, a.state as state, a.created_by as authorid, mp.group_id as groupid, ug.title as ugtitle
        FROM #__content AS a
        LEFT JOIN #__categories AS cc ON a.catid = cc.id
        LEFT JOIN #__users AS u ON u.id = a.created_by
        LEFT JOIN #__cck_store_item_content AS av ON av.id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN #__comprofiler AS ua ON user_id = a.created_by
        LEFT JOIN #__cck_store_item_cck_store_item_content AS ar ON ar.id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN #__user_usergroup_map AS mp ON mp.user_id = a.created_by
        LEFT JOIN #__usergroups AS ug ON ug.id = mp.group_id
        LEFT JOIN #__session AS ss ON ss.userid = u.id AND ss.userid > 0 AND ss.guest = 0
        WHERE a.created_by = u.id  AND a.id >0
        AND DATE(a.created) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL ".(int)$safe_date." DAY) AND a.access = 1 AND a.state = 1 AND a.created > 0
        ORDER BY created desc";
        $db->setQuery($query,0,10);
        $lists = $db->loadObjectList();         

        return $lists;
    }
```

It works like a charm, but heres some strange part, if I login same user from different browser, it duplicates all of my content twice, and if I login for the third time, it duplicates all content 3 times and so on! As far as I can see the problem is in this line:

```
LEFT JOIN #__session AS ss ON ss.userid = u.id AND ss.userid > 0 AND ss.guest = 0
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you joining to the session table?

Comment: I need to know if given author is currently online, is it possible to do without joining?

Comment: and if you do `select distinct`?

Comment: @AndrewSekaev I updated my answer with the correct solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It duplicates because logging from another browser creates a new session for that user. Try to do

```
SELECT DISTINCT
...
```

Comment: after grouping ss.userid I get only 2 results instead of 10...:( im kinda lost here

Comment: Just look out for legitimate duplicates, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add an alias to this user_id, so the database knows what table this user_id refers to.

`LEFT JOIN #__comprofiler AS ua ON user_id = a.created_by`

I would run smaller versions of the query and see when the duplicates start getting introduced. Start with the first 3 table joins. And if you don't see duplicates add one more join, so you are joining the first four tables in your query. Will help find exactly where the problem is being introduced.

Comment: I'v added alias but no luck, and the problem dissapears if i take JOIN #__Session out, so #__Session causes duplicating...

Comment: Oh. You need the user id in your where clause. This query is running for all users. You aren't specifying which user is logged in in the WHERE.

Comment: Hm, thats because im not getting it for specific user, its a list. Later on I do what you suggest in foreach $item->onlineid

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what your problem is now. If additional logins are cause duplicate rows you are going to have to add user id somewhere. Maybe not on the #_users table, but maybe on the #_sessions table.